Merge two indices value by a common field in elasticsearch
PUT _enrich/policy/merge
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "es.event-154.23-09-01-6-27-22",
    "match_field": "ancestor_id",
    "enrich_fields":  ["status","status_id","type","sub_type","primary_assigned","vehicle_of_interest","dms_ro_number","dms_deal_number","primary_assigned_user_name","dealership_id", "ancestor_id","event_id","deleted","service_date","update_date","secondary_assigned_user_name","bdc_assigned_user_name"]
  }
}

PUT _ingest/pipeline/enrich
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "enrich": {
        "description": "Add Events to customer",
        "policy_name": "merge",
        "field": "contact_id",
        "target_field": "events",
        "max_matches": "1"
        
        
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "es.customer-154.24-08-09-6-27-22"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "es.customerevent1-154.25-08-09-6-27-22",
    "pipeline": "enrich"
  }
}

Here, I am trying to add some values to the indices. If it is more matches there then which record should it take? . It looks like it took a random record by match field. Is possible to mention to match with specific order asc/desc by a field? Please help me to fix this.

Great progress so far!!
One way to achieve this is to store all matches in an array (here 10 matches stored in tmpArray and then pick the one that suits you best using a script processor (here tmpArray is sorted by someFieldand we store the first one in the event field), like this:
PUT _ingest/pipeline/enrich
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "enrich": {
        "description": "Add Events to customer",
        "policy_name": "merge",
        "field": "contact_id",
        "target_field": "tmpArray",
        "max_matches": "10"
        
        
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "if": "ctx.tmpArray != null",
        "source": """
        Integer sortByEventId(Map o1, Map o2) {
          return o1.event_id != null && o2?.event_id != null ? o2.event_id.compareTo(o1.event_id) : 0;
        }
        ctx.events = ctx.tmpArray.stream()
          .sorted(this::sortByEventId)
          .limit(5)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

        ctx.remove('tmpArray');
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}


Here, we are storing the first one in the event field, but I need at least 5 items to store. Could you change the query accordingly since I am new to the painless script. Thank you for your response.

I need top 5 items by descending the field event_id

I've updated the script accordingly

The sort was not working properly. I have more than 10000 events_id per contact_id.

Because max_matches is 10 and I think the maximum is 128, so 10K is a bit too much I'm afraid.

I need top 5 by desc out of 10k

@balan There is a sort processor. Not sure if it works but you can add it into the ingest pipeline and try it.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-processor.html

@MusabDogan the problem is that the enrich processor is not able to pull more than 128 matching records.

Thanks for your feedback @Val. He is looking for top 5, so I thought maybe pre-sorting can help him to sort descending and in that way he can find the top 5.

@musab the source index of the enrich policy (i.e. es.event-154.23-09-01-6-27-22) can contain up to 10K events for a given contact and the enrich processor will only allow to match up to 128. So that sorting would need to happen before enrichment, but unfortunately the enrich policy doesn't provide that capability

Make sense. Thanks for letting me know @Val
